# to get iteration count and total count over the rows from a column in table

Tags: python, sql, bash

We have a database table(source) with some million records in a table : Sample data like (extracted to a text file for sample)

```
 denied the payment
 the payment successfull and incident reported successfull
 Incident is been reported
```

while trying to get the distint words count on these 3 records . have replaced space with new line character and then sort uniq we have done .

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file|sort|uniq -c >> new.txt 
output: 
denied   1
the      2
payment  2
successfull 2
Incident 2
is       1
been     1
reported 2
```

how can we also get number of rows for the above output: some thing like

```
values iterationcount    countofrows

denied              1       1
the                 2       2
payment             2       2 
successfull         2       1  (Although this word is two times but available only in 1 row )
Incident            2       2
is                  1       1
been                1       1
reported            2       2
```

Comment: How is this related to Python or SQL?

Comment: @MichaelButscher i am trying to check the possibility if it can be achieved in sql or python as the source is from database

Answer (score 2):

You can't start by converting blanks to newlines and then try to add getting counts per the original lines.

Using any awk that supports `delete array` (which is most of them):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    delete seen
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        wordCnt[$i]++
        if ( !seen[$i]++ ) {
            rowCnt[$i]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    print "values", "iterationcount", "countofrows"
    for ( word in wordCnt ) {
        print word, wordCnt[word], rowCnt[word]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s $'\t' -t
values       iterationcount  countofrows
payment      2               2
incident     1               1
the          2               2
and          1               1
been         1               1
reported     2               2
successfull  2               1
Incident     1               1
is           1               1
denied       1               1
```